# CCLayoutBox in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Is there something similar to a CCLayoutBox in Cocos2d-x? I'm looking around Cocos Studio, but find nothing. I want a node that can space out its children over an area with unknown width and/or height - so that the individual components will be equally dispersed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with CCLayoutBox but I think what you want is [`Layout`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.5/d2/db7/classcocos2d_1_1ui_1_1_layout.html). There are some [examples](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Containers) on the wiki that explain how to use it. Here's one of them:

```
// Create the layout
    Layout* layout = Layout::create();
    layout->setLayoutType(LayoutType::VERTICAL);
    layout->setContentSize(Size(280, 150));
    Size backgroundSize = background->getContentSize();
    layout->setPosition(Vec2((widgetSize.width - backgroundSize.width) / 2.0f +
                              (backgroundSize.width - layout->getContentSize().width) / 2.0f,
                              (widgetSize.height - backgroundSize.height) / 2.0f +
                              (backgroundSize.height - layout->getContentSize().height) / 2.0f));
    _uiLayer->addChild(layout);


    Button* button = Button::create("cocosui/animationbuttonnormal.png", "cocosui/animationbuttonpressed.png");
    layout->addChild(button);

    LinearLayoutParameter* lp1 = LinearLayoutParameter::create();
    button->setLayoutParameter(lp1);
    lp1->setGravity(LinearLayoutParameter::LinearGravity::CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    lp1->setMargin(Margin(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f));


    Button* titleButton = Button::create("cocosui/backtotopnormal.png", "cocosui/backtotoppressed.png");
    titleButton->setTitleText("Title Button");
    layout->addChild(titleButton);

    LinearLayoutParameter* lp2 = LinearLayoutParameter::create();
    titleButton->setLayoutParameter(lp2);
    lp2->setGravity(LinearLayoutParameter::LinearGravity::CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    lp2->setMargin(Margin(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f));


    Button* button_scale9 = Button::create("cocosui/button.png", "cocosui/buttonHighlighted.png");
    button_scale9->setScale9Enabled(true);
    button_scale9->setContentSize(Size(100.0f, button_scale9->getVirtualRendererSize().height));
    layout->addChild(button_scale9);

    LinearLayoutParameter* lp3 = LinearLayoutParameter::create();
    button_scale9->setLayoutParameter(lp3);
    lp3->setGravity(LinearLayoutParameter::LinearGravity::CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    lp3->setMargin(Margin(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f));
```

"Setting three parameters for layout - LinearLayoutParameter, Gravity and Margin, then set layout parameters for three UIPanel's inner widgets.

Here we used Linear Vertical scheme, but every Gravity set as `LinearLayoutParameter::LinearGravity::CENTER_HORIZONTAL` that is displaying as center horizontally. Margin shows the spacing around the edges, notice that the value of lp2 is `UIMargin(20, 20, 0, 5)`, which means the spacing from left, top, right and button. When left spacing is 20 you can see textButton's position has little offset to right. Except for the direction, other setting of layout vertical scheme is same as horizontal scheme. And two schemes are called Linear Layout, they using the same parameters."

Comment: I'm back... this looks confusing to me. Are we supposed to set the rules for the layout on each element? With CCLayoutBox we just set the rules on the outer layoutbox, then any element added to it will line up nicely and we don't have to set position for each element manually.

Comment: I finally tried this out, and I believe Layout cannot do anything like CCLayoutBox. The biggest reason is that anything added to a Layout must inherit from UIWidget, that is buttons etc, so we cannot just add any Node to it. With CCLayoutBox we can add anything inheriting from a simple CCNode so it's very easy to layout lines and columns and make grids.